# VS2013 label text screen update from variablechanged raised event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, integer, label

I have no idea how to resolve this...

I have a main MDI form, that reads an Arduino's analog pins from sensors. I take the serial communication and analyse it, that's all figured out.

Inside this main form, I want child forms for each of the analog pins, with a label representing the analog value.

I created a class "myVar" to raise an event when the value changes:

```
Public Class myVar
Private mValue As Integer
Public Event VariableChanged(ByVal mValue As Integer)

Public Property Variable As Integer
    Get
        Variable = mValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        mValue = value
        RaiseEvent VariableChanged(mValue)
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

On my child form, I simply have:

```
Public Class WasteVacuum
Public WithEvents value As New myVar

Private Sub WasteVacuum_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MdiParent = Main
End Sub

Private Sub VariableChanged(ByVal NewValue As Integer) Handles value.VariableChanged
    waste_lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(value.Variable)
    waste_lbl.Refresh()
    Console.WriteLine(value.Variable & " - " & waste_lbl.Text)
End Sub
```

End Class

My main form modify the child form's "value" according to the reading of the serial connection.
The "VaraibleChanged" seems to be working great, but my label "waste_lbl" won't update on the screen!!!

Here is the result in the console (value.variable - waste_lbl.text):

```
0 - 0
0 - 0
0 - 0
0 - 0
0 - 0
0 - 0
0 - 0
5 - 5
38 - 38
87 - 87
130 - 130
152 - 152
163 - 163
179 - 179
190 - 190
201 - 201
212 - 212
222 - 222
233 - 233
244 - 244
255 - 255
266 - 266
271 - 271
282 - 282
288 - 288
298 - 298
309 - 309
320 - 320
331 - 331
336 - 336
342 - 342
342 - 342
```

It looks like my label is properly taking the variable value, but why won't it update on the screen??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out myself...cross thread operations from form to form. 
Changing forms variable from my main form like this:

```
Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() A2_frm.val.Variable = A2.Variable)
```

fixed this issue.